# How to change google mail login?

Tags: support, login

I'm using my Gmail account as login for Stack Overflow and various other Stack Exchange sites. Now, I have changed my Gmail address and I would like to change my login here, too.

Is there a way this can be achieved?

Comment: How did you change address? You created new account on Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow these steps,

- Go to your profile,
- Click on "my logins" link,
- Add new Email.

> [image]

Now Click on "my logins"

> [image]

Now Click on "add more logins" link and add new email.

Comment: How can I remove the old entries? I don't see any remove buttons.

Comment: @DevilsChild, can you see "remove" link in the above image ? Using it you can remove current one.

Comment: Actually, all I see is this: http://dev-ch.com/files/d6bb8a96-dc01-ec54-4ab6-6e68379c7ec4/stackexchangelogins.jpg
Is it possible that I'm on the wrong page?

Comment: Oh, right... I *was* on the wrong page. Instead of StackExchange, I had to look on meta.stackoverflow.com for it. Thank you, you really saved my day :)